# New TEXLIVE install, pdflatex working but packages not found

Tags: installing

I'm embarassed by this but but it all resulted from me putting my Ubuntu OS into a coma. I got a new PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu (linux) installed as dual operating systems. I rarely use Windows but I installed TeXLive 2021 from the DVD into the Ubuntu side of things. Running `pdflatex` on `sample2e.tex` (one of the example files) worked fine, but when I tried to process anything but the example files (e.g. same class but with with packages or a different class) all failed because the package/class files could not be found although they are on my computer in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex'

How do I get `pdflatex` and friends to find these extra class/package files? I have tried  setting environment variables like `TEXMFLOCAL` to the above directory but they are still not found.

Comment: if sample2e.tex works it must load files. So check the log-file where it looks for things.

Comment: Or try with `kpsewhich article.cls`.

Comment: @Skillmon I did `kpsewhich article.cls` and it returned `\usr/share\texlive\texmf-dist\tex\latex\base\article.cls`. I also did `kpsewhich memoir.cls` which returned nothing.

Comment: @PeterWilson maybe your ls-R files aren't correct. Try rebuilding them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I checked the log file but all it reported was that the `.sty` files were not found.

Comment: sorry but  how could sample2e.tex then compile? Show the complete sample2e.log.

Comment: you have not put the texlive you installed in your path, your comment shows that kpsewhich (and presumably pdftex) are the system tex using files in /usr/share/texlive not the one you installed in .usr/local/texlive/2021.  Edit your `.profile` to add /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bin/whatever to the front of your PATH

Comment: see **Post Install** at https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I finally went with @DavidCarlisle. I had tried adjusting the PATH but that only worked for the particular terminal window. Editing the `.proflle` file (once I had found it) then logging off and on again fixed my problem. It's been well over 10 years since I had to do such things and memory fades. Thank goodness you keep yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not put the texlive you installed in your path, your comment shows that kpsewhich (and presumably pdftex) are the system tex using files in

```
/usr/share/texlive
```

not the one you installed in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021
```

Edit your .profile to add

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bin/x86_64-linux
```

to the front of your PATH, eg a line such as

export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH

(You will need to log in again to see the effect of a an edit to `.profile`)

see **Post Install** at https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at `.profile`. It's been over ten years since I had to tweak it and it had faded from my memory (as have many other things).